# Error occurring on truncate table within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, truncate, user-permissions

I have a very strange situation that I have tried to research the answer from the Net to no avail. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have created a stored procedure that has a  `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement on it amongst other T-SQL statements.

When this is run from SQL Server Management Studio, the stored procedure runs without error.

When run from a Windows Forms application (written in VB.Net with .NET Framework 4), I am getting the error

> *Cannot find the object tbl_Test1 because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permissions*

The connection to the database is set within the application correctly, and what is even stranger is that I have other stored procedures created in exactly the same way, with their own `TRUNCATE TABLE` statements and these still run without error.

There is execute permission on the stored procedure to the `User_Role`, of which the calling application is logging on as.

The table `tbl_Test1` DOES exist.

I have tried several things and from doing this, have become even more confused about this whole situation.

1. If I put a `Select * from tbl_Test1` prior to the `TRUNCATE`, then the stored procedure works.
2. Because I am returning a select later on, I would prefer this not be present. So I recoded and did a `select @Count = count(*) from tbl_Test1` before the `TRUNCATE` statement, and this fails with the same error above stating the `tbl_Test1` doesn't exist or no permission.

I am at a complete loss as to why this might occur. I have several other stored procedures that have truncate statements within them, created in exactly the same way as this one and those work fine when called from the application.

Can anyone help or shed some light on my problem.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: We're pretty bad at debugging when we're not allowed to see the code.

Comment: All the code in the stored procedure is a TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_Test1 along with other SQL Statements. The reason for not actually putting in the code is that i dont think it adds anything to the problem. The issue is that the SP works perfectly ok from within Management Studio but doesnt from VB.NET app. If there are no Truncate statements in my SP then it works fine (inc delete and select and update). I can see no reason why the Truncate would not work when it does in Management Studio. Am happy to post the code if you think it will really help in this issue.

Answer (score 10):

Ownership chaining [doesn't apply](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#notallperms) to `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

You need to grant that permission explicitly ([the minimum permission required is `ALTER` on table_name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)) or use `EXECUTE AS` in the stored procedure. Giving `EXEC` permissions on the stored procedure is not enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - the EXECUTE As was the way to go as you said.